# MVVM Pass-Through Binding

Tags: c#, mvvm

How can I create a view model that in some cases one of its properties refers to a static object while in others it refers to an instance and still preserve bindings?

Lets say I wanted my viewmodel for a "ShoppingCartPage" to look like this:

```
public class ShoppingCartViewModel
{
    public ShoppingCart Cart { get; set; }
    public void AddItem(Item item);
    public void RemoveItem(Item item);
    public ShoppingCartViewModel(ShoppingCart cart)
    {
        Cart = cart;
    }
}
```

Now, my question is how can I pass in a static instance of Cart and still allow bindings from View to Viewmodel to work.

Edit:

I have a static DataAccess class in which I declare a singleton/static instance of Cart:

```
public static class DataAccess
{
    public static Cart UserCart = new Cart();
    ...
}
```

I use this to populate the cart from anywhere in the app.

I can create view which binds directly to this object.

However, I would rather move to a pattern in which I can handle serialized instances of Cart from the server like so:

```
public class ShoppingCartPage
{
    public ShoppingCartPage(ShoppingCartViewModel vm)
    {
        //psuedo code
        Label1.Bind(SomeProperty, vm.Cart);
    }
 }
```

That works for cases where vm.Cart has not changed. However, when the Cart is DataAccess.UserCart and I call DataAccess.UserCart.AddItem(New Item()), the VM is not aware of changes to this data.

Comment: _"how can I pass in a static instance of Cart"_ -- please define "static instance". That sounds like an oxymoron to me. Also, please explain what "work" means. Fix your question so that it includes a good [mcve] showing clearly what you've tried and/or would like the code to do. Explain _precisely_ what that code does now, and what you want it to do instead. It is not at all clear from your post right now what it is you'd like to be able to do, nor what behavior it is you want from the code.

Answer (score 0):

I really over thought it here. I was not sure if my Cart class was a model or view model or something else and I was trying to fit it into one of these but all I really needed was events to make the ShoppingCartViewModel aware of changes in the Cart!